# How to set boxes for animated gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to do an animated gif with contours from the dataset that looks like this:

```
"{/:Italic t} = 0 [yr]
-0.98   -0.98   0   0
-0.94   -0.98   0   0
-0.9    -0.98   0   0
-0.86   -0.98   0   0
-0.82   -0.98   0   0
-0.78   -0.98   0   0
...


"{/:Italic t} = 0.317 [yr]
-0.98   -0.98   0   -2.21572
-0.94   -0.98   0   -2.20023
-0.9    -0.98   0   -2.17084
-0.86   -0.98   0   -2.13024
-0.82   -0.98   0   -2.08149
...
```

gnuplot script is:

```
reset
set terminal gif animate delay 40
set contour
unset surface
set cntrparam levels incr -3,0.5,1
set output filename
set ylabel "{/:Italic z} [m]"
set xlabel "{/:Italic x} [m]"
set cblabel "{/:Italic x} [%]"
set cbrange [0:0.01]
set rmargin at screen 0.8
set palette defined ( 0 '#000090',\
                      1 '#000fff',\
                      2 '#0090ff',\
                      3 '#0fffee',\
                      4 '#90ff70',\
                      5 '#ffee00',\
                      6 '#ff7000',\
                      7 '#ee0000',\
                      8 '#7f0000')

set key center tmargin
set style textbox noborder

do for [i=0:9] {
    set dgrid3d 50,50,1
    set table $COUNTOUR
    splot data u 1:2:4 index i
    unset table
    unset key
    plot data index i with image title columnheader(1), $COUNTOUR w l lc rgb "white", '' u 1:2:3 every 50 w labels boxed tc rgb "white"
}
```

That produces:

[image]

I have 2 questions:

1. How to add invisible boxes for contours? I was trying to reimplement a thing that I've reused from the static example that works:

```
reset
set contour
unset surface
set cntrparam levels incr 0,1,4
set xrange [-0.5:0.5]
set yrange [-0.5:0.5]
set ylabel "{/:Italic z} [m]"
set xlabel "{/:Italic x} [m]"
set cblabel "({/:Italic P}) [Pa]"
set title 'P map + Tii contour'
set dgrid3d 100,100,1
set table $COUNTOUR
splot data u 1:2:4
unset table
unset key
if (!exists("filename")) filename='../VISUAL_TESTS/img/ShearTemplate.png'
set terminal png size 800,600;
set output filename;
set style textbox noborder
load 'inferno.pal'
plot data with image, data using 1:2:($5/10):($6/10) with vectors lc -1 filled, $COUNTOUR w l lc rgb "white", '' u 1:2:3 every 50 w labels boxed tc rgb "white"
```

2. Why all the sudden my dynamic title is not showing up after I've added contours? It comeletely ignores my `with image title columnheader(1)`

Comment: 1. What exactly do you mean with "invisible boxes for contours"? Do you maybe mean  interruptions of the contour line such that the label is not crossed by the contour line? 2. where is your "title" option in the plot command of the second example?

Comment: You don't give feedback, apparently, because there is no interest in an answer. So, why are you asking then?